# Why do s3 requests with the default region fail when signed with AWS4 signatures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a request to an s3 endpoint with no region in it.

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject
```

When I generate the signatures for the `us-east-1` region, and make a request, it fails.

```
400 Bad Request
Request Error.
```

This is singularly unhelpful.

If I make a request to the bucket with the region `us-east-1`, it works perfectly.

```
https://mybucket.us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject
```

The only real differences I can see are the `Host: us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com` in the headers, and the fact that the request will be going to the specific `us-east-1` endpoint.

In all the documentation I've been able to find, Amazon states that if a region is left out, it will use `us-east-1`, and that region should be used when calculating the AWS4 signature.

My question is - am I correct in assuming that requests to `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com` should be signed with AWS4 signatures calculated with the `us-east-1` region? If not, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why is this an issue? Just use the url with `us-east-1` in it.

Comment: @jellycsc, because it used to work without the region when using AWS2 signatures, so this is technically a regression. Our software allows the users to specify their own url's, and I don't know if I should parse them and modify the url to include a region if none is provided, or if I'm doing something wrong when creating the signatures.